# Is it possible not to mention all the script file paths in grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I am using gruntjs and usemin task.
I added this to my html file:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/all.js -->
<script src="../../core/module.js"></script>
<script src="../../core/base/alerts/alert-item.js"></script>
<script src="../../core/base/alerts/alerts-list.js"></script>
<script src="../../core/base/base_model.js"></script>
<script src="../../core/base/cursor.js"></script>
<script src="../../core/...<another script>...."></script>
<script src="../../core/...<another script>...."></script>
<script src="../../core/...<another script>...."></script>
<script src="../../core/...<another script>...."></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

As you can see, all the scripts are located in `../../core` How can I tell usemin to take first `../../core/module.js` and then `../../core/**/*` without mention each and every file?
Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

For grunt task configurations you can use globing patterns to build a file list dynamically.

Have a look at the two consecutive paragraphs on 'Globbing patterns' and 'Building the files object dynamically' in the gruntjs doc:
http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns

If you paste your usimin task configuration, it would be possible to help you building the right pattern

Comment: Assuming I have all the list of scripts (using the glob method in the Gruntfile), how can I add those scripts to my html file?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Based upon the comment and the fact you don't control all the code, an alternative to `usemin` would be to use a 'src' and 'dist' directory structure as demonstrated in the [sample gruntfile](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) to handle the bulk move/concat/uglify.

1. In the source HTML, reference the file that will be generated in your 'dist' directory by the grunt tasks.
2. Configure `grunt-watch` to `copy`, `concat` and `uglify` the files from 'src' upon a change.
3. When you need to test or upload to production, you can do it out of 'dist' without worrying about what scripts may have been added or changed in 'src'.
4. If you are just adding new files from the other project, you can create and call a 'build' task that does the same three tasks as `grunt-watch` does in #3.

If you poke around, you can find examples of this approach in several javascript frameworks that you can borrow and modify to your needs.  [This article](http://chrisawren.com/posts/Advanced-Grunt-tooling) might be useful.

**Original:**

Based upon this and your other question asked today, it sounds like [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) might not be the right tool for your need.  Something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) would cut the number of script tags in your HTML but would shift the need to enumerate them to a different file/location...and your complaint seems to be with writing all of the scripts as a manifest/list in the code.

Grunt offers a way to handle files en masse, but that's best utilized when copying directories or doing other similar low-risk bulk work.  Thus, you can find ways to get usemin to bulk load without logic, but I suggest it is generally bad practice to "load all the javascripts".  ...but if that's what you want, I would ask you why a bulk concatenate and uglify isn't the answer.

The benefits of a manifest or explicitly listing the files become more visible as a project grows in size or complexity. An innocent mistake that adds/removes a file from the directory can cause confusion and the cause isn't instantly clear.  Listing the files explicitly in the HTML would cause `usemin` to throw an error if one was missing in the directory and later, you can also audit the directory to see what is still lingering even though it is no longer used.  Globbing them would not offer either of these benefits.

Without a manifest, things can be solved through judicious use of a VCS and a review of changes since the last commit...but that's not as easy or as fun as saying "Hey, *script.js* got deleted and that's causing `usemin` to barf so somebody owes me a beverage for replacing the file and getting the build working again!"

Comment: I understand what you says. But a lot of scripts are added to our project and I don't want to remember to add the script in the manifest. More than that, those files are actually a dependencies from other project. I don't own this project and any change in it will cause a change in the manifest. I just need to load the module.js and the rest of the files.

Comment: Just remembered: you might also look at the Gruntfile generated by [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) as I believe they do something similar to what you are asking (take files from a directory, build an output file, and inject the name into the HTML).

Comment: Can't I override somehow the concat and uglify configurations of useminPrepare and declare there the scripts I want? If there is such way, do you know how? I don't manage to do it..

Comment: Not really, no.  Also, usemin is creating configurations for concat and uglify and you can call each of those directly without adding complexity by trying to bend usemin to do something it wasn't built to do.  I'd say you should either try to keep the list of files in your HTML or shift to using concat and uglify directly as I suggested because that meets your stated requirements with the least work, low complexity, and low ongoing maintenance cost.